# SonarQube - Unable to execute Java command. Access is denied. (0x5)

Tags: java, sonarqube

When starting SonarQube (v8.3) it get this error:

> Unable to execute Java command.  Access is denied. (0x5) ... ...
> wrapper  | wrapper  |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ wrapper  | Advice: wrapper  | Access denied errors when attempting to
> launch the Java process are wrapper  | usually caused by strict access
> permissions assigned to the directory wrapper  | in which Java is
> installed. wrapper  |
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ wrapper  | wrapper  | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed

I have set all the permissions that are obvious on the java folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4`

This is running on a newly installed Windows 2016 Server.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you added the jdk binaries to the system PATH, on enviroment variables.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-x.x.x\bin\java

Answer (score 4):

Update Java path like below in your SonarQube/Conf/wrapper.conf file

wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java

This solved my problem. Hope it work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: So i need to install Java to use SonarQube ?

Comment: does it not work with  java 8?

Answer (score 0):

Let the wrapper command be:
wrapper.java.command=java

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).